# Accurate timestamping in Bash with printf (not a trivial problem)

Tags: bash, timestamps, printf

Shell: Bash.

Goal: obtain time t in milliseconds since some fixed point in time, suitable for timestamping stuff with printf.

Condition: the solution must pass the all-in-one-line-of-text test.

Additional: the solution should be atomic (yeah, right!..), lightweight, keep quantization & rounding issues to a minimum, blah..

`t=$[$(date +%s%N)/1000000]` <--- my solution, the fixed point being Jan 1, 1970 in this case. BUT fundamentally bad due to the two date calls.

`printf "t=%d\n" $[$(date +%s%N)/1000000]` <--- here it is, using printf.

`t=$(date +%s)$[10#$(date +%N)/1000000]` <--- terrible example. Even seems to need de-pad of, then re-pad with, leading zeros.

`printf "t=%d%03d\n" $(date +%s) $[10#$(date +%N)/1000000]` <--- here it is, using printf.

Any better (sensible) suggestions?

EDIT (appending):

`t=$(date +%s%N)` and then `printf "%s\n" ${t::13}` <--- I guess, but not one line.

Comment: How is `t=$[$(date +%s%N)/1000000]` "two date calls" ?

Comment: I suspected that the %s was one, and the %N was another. Is this incorrect?

Comment: No, `date` is run, once, makes a system get-time call, then fills in the template of `%s%N` with the information from the system call, and emits that data.

Comment: @thrig: Ah, thanks! Which would make your first comment redundant :( Reductionism should be practiced universally.

Comment: It's fine to ask for a bash-specific solution, but it's counter-productive to ask answerers *not* give solutions for other shells. This Q&A would be useful to more people without it as not all people are restricted to using `bash` or could have the same requirement in other shells.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I agree; I've removed that part of the question.  It would be different if there were already a Q&A on this site that extensively addressed the same question for *other* shells to the point where this question would be dupe-closed *without* the "just bash" restriction (that happens sometimes).  But since it hasn't been, this *is* the general question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted by @Isaac, with `date` implementations that support `%N` like GNU's or ast-open's, you can use `%s%3N` to limit the precision, but except in `ksh93` where `date` *can* be made to be the builtin version of ast-open's `date`, the `date` command is not builtin. It will take a few hundred if not thousand microseconds to start and a few more to print the date and return.

`bash` did copy a subset of `ksh93` `printf '%(...)T'` format, but not the `%N` part.

Here it looks like you'd need to use more advanced shells like `ksh93` or `zsh`.

Those shells can make their `$SECONDS` variable which records the time since the shell started (and that you can also reset to any value) floating point:

```
$ typeset -F SECONDS=0; date +%s%3N; echo $SECONDS
1506318780647
0.0017870000
```

It took up to 1787 microseconds to run GNU `date` here.

You can use `$((SECONDS*1000))` to get a number of milliseconds as both shells support floating point arithmetic (beware `ksh93` honours the locale's decimal mark).

For the epoch time as a float, `zsh` has `$EPOCHREALTIME`:

```
$ zmodload zsh/datetime
$ echo $EPOCHREALTIME
1506318947.2758708000
```

And `ksh93` can use `"$(printf '%(%s.%N)T' now)"` (note that `ksh93`'s command substitution doesn't fork processes nor use pipes for builtins so is not as expensive as in other Bourne-like shells).

You could also define the `$EPOCHREALTIME` variable there with:

```
$ EPOCHREALTIME.get() { .sh.value=$(printf "%(%s.%6N)T");
$ echo "$EPOCHREALTIME"
1506333341.962697
```

For automatic timestamping, you can also use `set -o xtrace` and a `$PS4` that prints the current time. In `zsh`:

```
$ zsh -c 'PS4="+%D{%s.%.}> "; set -x; sleep 1; date +%s.%N'
+1506332128.753> sleep 1
+1506332129.754> date +%s.%N
1506332129.755322928
```

In ksh93:

```
$ ksh -c 'PS4="+\$(printf "%(%s.%3N)T")> "; set -x; sleep 1; date +%s.%N'
+1506332247.844> sleep 1
+1506332248.851> date +%s.%N
1506332248.853111699
```

Depending on your use case, you may be able to rely on `moreutils`'s `ts` for your time-stamping:

```
$ (date +%s.%6N; date +%s.%6N) | ts %.s
1506319395.000080 1506319394.970619
1506319395.000141 1506319394.971972
```

(`ts` gives the time it read the line from `date`'s output through the pipe).

Or for time between lines of output:

```
$ (date +%s.%6N; date +%s.%6N) | ts -i %.s
0.000011 1506319496.806554
0.000071 1506319496.807907
```

If you want to get the time it took to run a given command (pipeline), you can also use the `time` keyword, adjusting the format with `$TIMEFORMAT` in `bash`:

```
$ TIMEFORMAT=%E; time date
Mon 25 Sep 09:51:41 BST 2017
0.002
```

Those time format directives initially come from csh (though `bash`, contrary to `zsh` or GNU `time` only supports a tiny subset). In (t)csh, you can time every command by setting the `$time` special variable:

```
$ csh -xc 'set time = (0 %E); sleep 1; sleep 2'
set time = ( 0 %E )
sleep 1
0:01.00
sleep 2
0:02.00
```

(the first number (`0` here) tells that commands that take more than that many seconds should be timed, the second specifies the format).

Answer (score 8):

Since bash5+ there is a simple solution:

```
$ printf "%.3f\n" $EPOCHREALTIME
1566917328.786
```

If the dot is not desired:

```
printf "%s\n" "$((${EPOCHREALTIME/.}/1000))"
```

Provide time in milliseconds since epoch all-in-one-line-of-text, atomic (one call to an internal bash variable), lightweight, and no quantization or rounding issues.

Comment: On my system running bash 5.0.17, `$EPOCHREALTIME` provides the time in microseconds so you'd need `"$(( ${EPOCHREALTIME/.} / 1000000 ))"`, or better yet: `"${EPOCHREALTIME%.*}"` which can deal with either milliseconds or microseconds.

Answer (score 3):

1. First the `date` tool is not part of the bash, it is an external tool.
2. Bash itself can't do it without external commands.
3. Doing this with external commands can't pass your single-line criterion.

Thus, you can't do it.

However, if you allow 2 lines, or you write a function for that, you can do it, as it was written in the comments.

*Extension:* you can do it with more recent bashes (>4.2), even as a single-line command, although it won't be the most simplest bash line you've ever wrote. Check the other answer.

Comment: Recent (4.2+ I think) versions of bash have strftime formats built in to printf: `printf '%(%F)T\n' $(date +%s)`

Comment: Well ... ... there is a kind of one liner way if you accept that a command expansion may be a part of a "one liner". Read my answer.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
$ date +'%s%3N'
1506298414529
```

#### bash

An strict bash solution (no external executables) is possible since bash 4.2:

```
$ printf '%(%s)T\n' "-1"
1506298414

$ printf '%(%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S)T\n' "-1"
20170924-20:13:34
```

But that doesn't allow milliseconds, nor nanoseconds (yet).

#### date

To get miliseconds or nanoseconds you need to use GNU date as this:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$(date +'%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S.%N')"
20170924-20:13:34.326113922
```

Or

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$(date +'%s.%N')"
1506298414.529678016
```

The limit to 3 digits in the fractional part of the seconds could be produced with a `%.3f` format for printf:

```
$ printf '%.3f\n' "$(date +'%s.%N')"
1506298414.529
```

Or better, use the ability to reduce the number of digits that the date nanoseconds format allow:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$(date +'%s.%3N')"
1506298414.529
```

And then, the dot could be removed:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$(date +'%s%3N')"
1506298414529
```

Of course, in this case, the simpler solution (without printf, instead of what was exactly asked) seems more apropiate:

```
$ date +'%s%3N'
1506298414529
```

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to just call `date +....` instead of `printf '%s\n' $(date...)`?

Comment: Yes, indeed, but the question ask for the use of printf (for whichever reasons the OP had): *... Accurate timestamping in Bash with printf ....* @JeffSchaller