# measure time spent reading history file when starting a new interactive bash shell

Tags: bash, performance, command-history

If I had a `sleep` command
or something else slowing down execution of `.bashrc`,
I can profile it to see the slow parts like this:

```
$ printf "set -x\nPS4='+\\\\t '\nexport  HISTFILE=empty\nsleep 4\ntrue\n" > mybashrc
$ > empty
$ time bash --rcfile mybashrc -i <<< exit
+ PS4='+\t '
+19:13:47 export HISTFILE=empty
+19:13:47 HISTFILE=empty
+19:13:47 sleep 4
+19:13:51 true
$ exit
+19:13:51 exit
exit

real    0m4.022s
user    0m0.010s
sys     0m0.010s
```

with
[other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394168/accurate-timestamping-in-bash-with-printf-not-a-trivial-problem)
[options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014823/how-to-profile-a-bash-shell-script-slow-startup)
for higher precision using GNU `date`.

But suppose I have a large bash history file,
something like this:

```
$ yes ls | head -n 9999999 > big-hist
$ du -sh big-hist
29M     big-hist
```

Now the shell startup is also slow (about four seconds on my machine),
but I can't see where the time is being spent,
only that it's some time after the last command of the `.bashrc`.

```
$ printf "set -x\nPS4='+\\\\t '\nexport HISTSIZE=-1\nexport HISTFILESIZE=-1\nexport HISTFILE=big-hist\ntrue\n" > mybashrc
$ time bash --rcfile mybashrc -i <<< exit
+ PS4='+\t '
+19:12:23 export HISTSIZE=-1
+19:12:23 HISTSIZE=-1
+19:12:23 export HISTFILESIZE=-1
+19:12:23 HISTFILESIZE=-1
+19:12:23 export HISTFILE=big-hist
+19:12:23 HISTFILE=big-hist
+19:12:23 true
$ exit
+19:12:27 exit
exit

real    0m4.184s
user    0m3.641s
sys     0m0.536s
```

The best guess I can think of is to run this:

```
$ time bash -i <<< exit
$ SHLVL=2 $ exit
exit

real    0m0.400s
user    0m0.326s
sys     0m0.075s
```

then add the last line of the `.bashrc`:

```
HISTFILE=/dev/null
```

and run again:

```
$ time bash -i <<< exit
$ exit
exit

real    0m0.081s
user    0m0.059s
sys     0m0.023s
```

although I'm not entirely sure
this measures only the time spent processing the history file.

(Note: if you try this for yourself,
it is highly important to remember to remove the last line of the `.bashrc`
once the timing is complete!)

This is of particular interest to me
because I have for several years
[enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457233/unlimited-bash-history)
[unlimited history](https://superuser.com/questions/137438/how-to-unlimited-bash-shell-history)
in my `.bashrc`
and have noticed the startup time of new interactive shells has been impacted;
by more than 300 ms, if the timing above is accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see a reason not to trust your measurement.

But you can run `bash` through `strace`; then you see in which order the files are opened:

```
$ strace -t -f -e trace=file bash -i <<<exit 2>&1 | grep -E 'open(at)?\(' ; fg
[...]
03:10:39 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/hl/.bashrc", O_RDONLY) = 4
03:10:39 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/hl/.DISPLAY", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 4
03:10:39 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/inputrc", O_RDONLY) = 4
03:10:39 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/inputrc.keys", O_RDONLY) = 4
03:10:39 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/inputrc.keys", O_RDONLY) = 4
03:10:39 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/inputrc.keys", O_RDONLY) = 4
03:10:39 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/hl/.inputrc", O_RDONLY) = 4
03:10:39 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/hl/.bash_history", O_RDONLY) = 4
03:10:39 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/hl/.bash_history", O_RDONLY) = 4
03:10:39 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
```

I don't know why the `fg` is necessary. Maybe that is something in my shell config that sends the shell to the background.